# After providing move in python code for tic tac toe, letter is not drawn on board

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

not able to proceed further after providing move number in Python code for tic tac toe. It asks for next move then cell number is provided but makeMove() method is not getting executed. It will ask again next move till dont press enter key twice. Please help me to resolve this code.

```html
 #Tic Tac Toe

import random

def drawBoard(board):
     # This function prints out the board that it was passed.

   # "board" is a list of 10 strings representing the board (ignore index 0)
     print('   |   |')
     print(' ' + board[7] + ' | ' + board[8] + ' | ' + board[9])
     print('   |   |')
     print('-----------')
     print('   |   |')
     print(' ' + board[4] + ' | ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[6])
     print('   |   |')
     print('-----------')
     print('   |   |')
     print(' ' + board[1] + ' | ' + board[2] + ' | ' + board[3])
     print('   |   |')

def inputPlayerLetter():
     # Lets the player type which letter they want to be.
    #
     letter = ''
     while not (letter == 'X' or letter == 'O'):
         #print('Do you want to be X or O?')
         #letter = input().upper()
  letter = (raw_input("Do you want to be X or O? ")).upper()
  print "Received input is : ", letter.upper()

     # 
     if letter == 'X':
         return ['X', 'O']
     else:
         return ['O', 'X']

def whoGoesFirst():
     # Randomly choose the player who goes first.
     if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
         return 'computer'
     else:
         return 'player'

def playAgain():
     print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
     return raw_input().lower().startswith('y')

def makeMove(board, letter, move):
     board[move] = letter
   
def isWinner(bo, le):
     # 
     # 
   return ((bo[7] == le and bo[8] == le and bo[9] == le) or # across the top
     (bo[4] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[6] == le) or # across the middle
     (bo[1] == le and bo[2] == le and bo[3] == le) or # across the bottom
     (bo[7] == le and bo[4] == le and bo[1] == le) or # down the left side
     (bo[8] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[2] == le) or # down the middle
     (bo[9] == le and bo[6] == le and bo[3] == le) or # down the right side
     (bo[7] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[3] == le) or # diagonal
     (bo[9] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[1] == le)) # diagonal

def getBoardCopy(board):
     # Make a duplicate of the board list and return it the duplicate.
     dupeBoard = []

     for i in board:
         dupeBoard.append(i)

     return dupeBoard

def isSpaceFree(board, move):
     # Return true if the passed move is free on the passed board.
     return board[move] == ' '

def getPlayerMove(board):
     # Let the player type in their move.
     move = ' '
     while move not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split() or not isSpaceFree(board, int(move)):
         print('What is your next move? (1-9)')
         move = raw_input()
     return int(move)

def chooseRandomMoveFromList(board, movesList):
     # Returns a valid move from the passed list on the passed board.
     # Returns None if there is no valid move.
     possibleMoves = []
     for i in movesList:
         if isSpaceFree(board, i):
             possibleMoves.append(i)

     if len(possibleMoves) != 0:
         return random.choice(possibleMoves)
     else:
         return None

def getComputerMove(board, computerLetter):
     # Given a board and the computer's letter, determine where to move and return that move.
     if computerLetter == 'X':
         playerLetter = 'O'
     else:
         playerLetter = 'X'

     # Here is our algorithm for our Tic Tac Toe AI:
     # First, check if we can win in the next move
     for i in range(1, 10):
         copy = getBoardCopy(board)
         if isSpaceFree(copy, i):
             makeMove(copy, computerLetter, i)
             if isWinner(copy, computerLetter):
                 return i

     # Check if the player could win on their next move, and block them.
     for i in range(1, 10):
         copy = getBoardCopy(board)
         if isSpaceFree(copy, i):
             makeMove(copy, playerLetter, i)
             if isWinner(copy, playerLetter):
                 return i

     # Try to take one of the corners, if they are free.
     move = chooseRandomMoveFromList(board, [1, 3, 7, 9])
     if move != None:
         return move

     # Try to take the center, if it is free.
     if isSpaceFree(board, 5):
         return 5

     # Move on one of the sides.
     return chooseRandomMoveFromList(board, [2, 4, 6, 8])

def isBoardFull(board):
     # Return True if every space on the board has been taken. Otherwise return False.
     for i in range(1, 10):
         if isSpaceFree(board, i):
             return False
     return True


print('Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!')

while True:
     # Reset the board
     theBoard = [' '] * 10
     playerLetter, computerLetter = inputPlayerLetter()
     turn = whoGoesFirst()
     print('The ' + turn + ' will go first.')
     gameIsPlaying = True

     while gameIsPlaying:
         if turn == 'player':
             # 
             drawBoard(theBoard)
             move = getPlayerMove(theBoard)
             
             if isWinner(theBoard, playerLetter):
                 drawBoard(theBoard)
                 print('Hooray! You have won the game!')
                 gameIsPlaying = False
             else:
                 if isBoardFull(theBoard):
                     drawBoard(theBoard)
                     print('The game is a tie!')
                     break
                 else:
                     turn = 'computer'

         else:
             # 
             move = getComputerMove(theBoard, computerLetter)
             makeMove(theBoard, computerLetter, move)

             if isWinner(theBoard, computerLetter):
                 drawBoard(theBoard)
                 print('The computer has beaten you! You lose.')
                 gameIsPlaying = False
             else:
                 if isBoardFull(theBoard):
                     drawBoard(theBoard)
                     print('The game is a tie!')
                     break
                 else:
                     turn = 'player'

     if not playAgain():
         break
```

Output :

Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!
Do you want to be X or O? x
Received input is :  X
The computer will go first.
   |   |
 O |   |

### |   |

|   |
   |   |

### |   |

|   |
   |   |
   |   |

What is your next move? (1-9)
5

|   |
 O |   |

### |   |

|   |
   |   |

### |   |

|   |
 O |   |
   |   |
What is your next move? (1-9)
5
   |   |
 O |   |

### |   |

|   |
 O |   |

### |   |

|   |
 O |   |
   |   |
The computer has beaten you! You lose.
Do you want to play again? (yes or no)

Comment: if the function isn't being called, then start checking into what conditions are causing it to be skipped. e.g. `if (somecondition) call_func`, then check into why `somecondition` isn't what you expect it to be.

Comment: Here is the below error that I am getting for above code
What is your next move? (1-9)
7
What is your next move? (1-9)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\TAX\testdemo\tic_tac_toe.py", line 156, in <module>
    move = getPlayerMove(theBoard)
  File "D:\TAX\testdemo\tic_tac_toe.py", line 82, in getPlayerMove
    move = input()
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: What is your next move? (1-9)
7
What is your next move? (1-9)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\TAX\testdemo\tic_tac_toe.py", line 156, in <module>
    move = getPlayerMove(theBoard)
  File "D:\TAX\testdemo\tic_tac_toe.py", line 82, in getPlayerMove
    move = input()
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: I'm running version 3.2, so I had to add parenthesis around print "Received input is : ", letter.upper(). But then your program worked.

Comment: @Ryan - I am using python26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `input()` call with `raw_input()` in `getPlayerMove` function.

Your code doesn't work, because `input()` is an equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`. If user puts a number then `input` returns an integer value. That means `move not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split()` is always `False`

Comment: Thank you.. it worked.. but the problem is now that if I gave a move for board[5], then X is not drawn there. Though every move of computer is drawn on board that can be seen but mine move.
Please guide me on this.

Comment: @NikhilKadam describe your steps from the very beginning

Comment: Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!
Do you want to be X or O? x
Received input is :  X
The computer will go first.
After this I can see computer's move on board but when I enter my move 

What is your next move? (1-9) 
8
I am not able to see X on that board its all I can see is computer's move.

Comment: Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!
Do you want to be X or O? x
Received input is :  X
The computer will go first.
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |
-----------
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |
-----------
   |   |
   |   | O
   |   |
What is your next move? (1-9)
6
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |
-----------
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |
-----------
   |   |
 O |   | O
   |   |
What is your next move? (1-9)
8
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |
-----------
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |
-----------
   |   |
 O | O | O
   |   |
The computer has beaten you! You lose.
Do you want to play again? (yes or no)
This is what happening

Comment: @NikhilKadam it is very hard to read your comments. Paste terminal transcript to pastebin or gist. Also it would be nice to have additional details: python version, exact code you run

Comment: I am using python 2.6 version

Comment: I have pasted output to my query. Please let me know if i am able to make you clear. The issue is that I am not able to draw my input on that tic tac toe board. the move that is drawn on board and is seen is only of computer

Comment: @NikhilKadam format it appropriately, please. Also you haven't posted the code you run

Comment: I have uploaded my updated code in code snippet above.
After that in output section, as you can see the user input value is X. but on board only computer's move of O is displayed and not user's input though he had provided its value.

Comment: @NikhilKadam you deliberately deleted `makeMove` call on player's turn. Obviously it won't show you player's moves

Comment: thank you.. I have missed out that method while updating code.. now its working fine